# What code executes when I use JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

When I develop jsp pages I use jstl.

For example I use same constructions

```
...
<c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object">
    <td>${object.name} </td>
</c:forEach>
...
```

I know that prefix `c` defines when I make include page. For `c` prefix:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

I suppose that somewhere behind the scenes executes code(maybe java code)

Is it truthful statement ?

How do this code connects with `uri`?

How it works in general?

Comment: The code JSTL tags are custom tags like any other. Consider reading a tutorial that covers making your own tags, both Java- and JSP-based.

Comment: Are **java-based** and **jsp-based** differenr ways for binding jstl tags and java code?

Comment: Searching for either should be enough to answer that question. JSP-based custom tags are custom tags written entirely in JSP. Java-based custom tags are written in Java.

Comment: [Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.servlet/com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.0/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/el/core/ForEachTag.java) the source code for `core:forEach` (v1.2).

Comment: nice link.  I have read a class but I don't see link between **uri** and java code

Answer (score 0):

here you can download the source code of JSTL: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstl12sourcesjar.htm

In there you will find the answer to your question: the connection between URI and prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

The URI is just an identifier.If you open the c.tld file in the jstl jar files, you will see this uri declared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

  <description>JSTL 1.1 core library</description>
  <display-name>JSTL core</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>c</short-name>
  <uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>
```

yes it does execute the code behind the scenes.

like for `<c:forEach>` you can refer to below link for source code
[click here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.servlet/com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.0/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/el/core/ForEachTag.java#ForEachTag)

Answer (score -1):

Using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

you can attach and browse the source code in IDE.